# Image size locally much larger than on Dockerhub

Tags: docker, dockerfile

my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
  ARG BASE_CONTAINER=jupyter/pyspark-notebook:spark-3.3.2

  FROM $BASE_CONTAINER

  LABEL author="Doublena"

  USER $NB_UID
```

When I do a docker build,

```
 docker build -t pyspark_jupyter:latest .
```

I get the following image :

```
pyspark_jupyter          latest    d7c367182493e   7 weeks ago     4.35GB
```

The size is 4.35GB which is HUGE.
However, on Docker Hub the size is listed as 1.42GB

https://hub.docker.com/layers/jupyter/pyspark-notebook/spark-3.3.2/images/sha256-1b45638359537bcf4b573e6f6a6931801b3beb0d07077d3b82aca97458560274?context=explore

Is the reason for the discrepancy that the image on Docker Hub is compressed but is uncompressed locally ?